# Formula to calculate bandwidth used in Java

Tags: java, formula, bandwidth

I've looked around a bit and cannot seem to find a good formula to fit my need. I have the following values for a single connection to an application

```
long elapsedTimeSeconds = (System.currentTimeMillis() - client.getCreationTime()) / 1000;
long totalBytesRead = conn.getReadBytes();
long totalBytesWritten = conn.getWrittenBytes();
```

I would like to calculate the amount of bandwidth used (read and write) for the elapsed period in Kbps.

Is this the correct formula for calculating each separately?

```
long readBandwidthUsed = (totalBytesRead / 1024) / elapsedTimeSeconds;
```

Comment: Could you provide a little more info, such as what 'conn' and 'client' are?

Comment: Sure but what they "are" doesn't relate to the answer. The client is a representation of a Flash Player and conn is an RTMPConnection instance. The long values are whats important here.

Comment: What is your question? (I don't see a question mark, nor anything wrong with your formula ...)

Comment: @meriton The formula should add the total bytes read and written first, but other than that, me neither.

Comment: That's the answer i was looking for, basically is that the correct formula? I just guessed from what I was reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this formula:

```
long bandwidthUsed = (totalBytes / 1024) / elapsedTimeSeconds;
```